# Installing greenlet with pip fails on MacOS 13.1

Tags: python, macos, zsh

I am trying to install greenlet in a virtualenv on my mac.

```
pip install greenlet
```

This renders the following output:

```
Collecting greenlet
  Using cached greenlet-2.0.1.tar.gz (163 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [98 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/leakcheck.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet_trash.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      running egg_info
      writing src/greenlet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/greenlet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/greenlet.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/greenlet.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'benchmarks/*.json'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_allocator.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_compiler_compat.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_cpython_compat.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_exceptions.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_greenlet.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_internal.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_refs.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_slp_switch.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_state.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_state_dict_cleanup.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_support.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_masm.asm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_masm.obj -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/greenlet
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/alexanderk/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/Development/Python-Dev/testCHat/env/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/greenlet/greenlet.o --std=gnu++11
      src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include <Python.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: greenlet
  Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for greenlet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/alexanderk/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/Development/Python-Dev/testCHat/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_weakref.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_gc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/leakcheck.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet_trash.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_throw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_tracing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_cpp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_contextvars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_extension_interface.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_generator_nested.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_stack_saved.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/test_leaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      running egg_info
      writing src/greenlet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/greenlet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/greenlet.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/greenlet.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'benchmarks/*.json'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'appveyor'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'src/greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_allocator.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_compiler_compat.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_cpython_compat.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_exceptions.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_greenlet.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_internal.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_refs.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_slp_switch.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_state.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_state_dict_cleanup.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/greenlet_thread_support.hpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/slp_platformselect.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/platform/setup_switch_x64_masm.cmd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_aarch64_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_alpha_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_amd64_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm32_ios.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_masm.asm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_masm.obj -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_arm64_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_csky_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_m68k_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_mips_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_aix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc64_linux.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_aix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_linux.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_macosx.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_ppc_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_riscv_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_s390_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_sparc_sun_gcc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x32_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.asm -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_masm.obj -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x64_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_msvc.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/platform/switch_x86_unix.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/platform
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      copying src/greenlet/tests/_test_extension_cpp.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/greenlet/tests
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet._greenlet' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/greenlet
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/alexanderk/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/Development/Python-Dev/testCHat/env/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/greenlet/greenlet.o --std=gnu++11
      src/greenlet/greenlet.cpp:16:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include <Python.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> greenlet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have read a multitude of similar problems and solutionsbut none of them seem to work.

My setuptools are up to date.

My wheel is up to date.

My python version is 3.9.6

My mac is up to date.

I have XCode commandline tools installed.

Please help me adress this error so I can install greenlet and other python packages (some packages install fine, others give the same error)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I added more specifications to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Turns out my whole pip/python-versions etc. mess was causing the issue.

I followed this wonderfully written article and everything is working now: https://gist.github.com/MuhsinFatih/ee0154199803babb449b5bb98d3475f7

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps followed from link that solved the problem. it will help future users with same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Was facing same issue while installing `sqlalchemy` for which `greenlet` is a supporting package.

Lowering the `greenlet` version resolved my issue:

```
pip install greenlet==1.1.0
```